# Why does using jQuery to append a div containing document.write break safari and firefox pages

Tags: jquery, append, document.write

Web pages viewed in Firefox or Safari break in the case where:

A div contains document.write and you append this div to another div using jQuery. By break, I mean the whole page is replaced by the contents of the document.write.

I have changed the code to avoid this issue, but I am trying to get an understanding of why it happens.

My assumption is the document.write is triggered whilst the object is being appended and then replaces the pages source, but I can't find the technical reason.

Can anybody help explain the reason for this issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why use document.write when you have jQuery?

Comment: Sorry for the late response.

The markup was being generated and could not be changed, it used document.write for various reasons in some places and I needed to move the content to another location using jQuery. Basically some nasty hacks.

I found other ways in the end to counter this problem by catching the document.write.

Answer (score 1):

This is because that's how `document.write` should work after full page load. It just clears the page and output its parameter.